# TextBox Binding Lost when typing directly using the Keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, webusercontrol

I Have a usercontrol that is being updated by another usercontrol via provided ValueProperty (see code Window.XAML Binding below) When my other usercontrol's property is being updated, the textbox is updated as well via Value Binding.

But When I directly type to the usercontrols textbox then use my other user control again. The textbox is never updated again. It seems that the ValueProperty of my TextBox UserControl's was overwritten. 
I am assuming that the Text={Binding...} was lost and overwritten when I directly typed in the TextBox.

```
//Window.XAML
<veraControls:veraCommandPanel Name="commandCTRL" Value="{Binding ElementName=MyKeyPad, Path=Value}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="360.057" Margin="0,266,-92.834,0" FontSize="42" FontFamily="lcdD" Foreground="LimeGreen" Height="54.901" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

//Here is my userControl
<UserControl x:Name="PART_command" x:Class="Vera.WPFControls.veraCommandPanel"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Height="Auto" Width="300"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Vera.WPFControls">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Name="PART_veraCommand" TargetType="{x:Type local:veraCommandPanel}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:veraCommandPanel}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox Height="55" Name="PART_txtCommand"  Text="{Binding ElementName=PART_command, Path=Value}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
//TextBox UserControl's Code Behind
namespace Vera.WPFControls
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for veraCommandPanel.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class veraCommandPanel : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public veraCommandPanel()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = this;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public static  DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(veraCommandPanel));

    //, new UIPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropChanged)));

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `TwoWay` binding, like this:

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=PART_command, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Ok I think i have tried this already but will try again. What I want to know is what am I doing wrong or what should not be done to avoid overwriting the Binding. I will inform you of the outcome. Thanks

Comment: It still didnt work, my scenario is this if I click a button from the first usercontrol textbox usercontrol is updated of whatever is the value of my first usercontrol, when i typed directly to textbox control then click the first usercontrol's button again it is not working anymore.

Comment: Wow It worked. But this time I used Mode=TwoWay to my first control. Because when I type directly to my textbox UserControl my first Controls value was not updated using TwoWay It gets updated as well. Thanks Very Much Jay. I voted you up!

Comment: Done. Sorry I'm newbie here. Thanks again.